# How to show part of a Bitmap programmatically using ClipDrawable?

Tags: android, image, bitmap

I'm trying to show a certain part of an image.

For example:
[image: 70% of Android icon]

I tried to set a `ClipDrawable` of an `ImageView` from a `Bitmap` using the code below, but it didn't show up.

```
BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap);
ClipDrawable clipDrawable = new ClipDrawable(bitmapDrawable, Gravity.LEFT, ClipDrawable.HORIZONTAL);
clipDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
clipDrawable.setLevel(5000);
imageView.setImageDrawable(clipDrawable);
```

I also tested to make sure the problem wasn't with the `BitmapDrawable` by seeing if `imageView.setImageDrawable(bitmapDrawable)` would show the full image and it did display it correctly.

How can I show a fraction of a `Bitmap` using `ClipDrawable`?

Why is the image not showing up?

I looked at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18073588/androidhow-can-i-show-a-part-of-image), but the accepted answer assumes that the image can be retrieved from the resources whereas I'm loading my image dynamically.

The answers to the post [android - How to cut some part of image and show it in imageview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12837523/android-how-to-cut-some-part-of-image-and-show-it-in-imageview) don't answer my question using `ClipDrawable` and just use magic numbers to create a new `Bitmap`.

The [Android docs on `ClipDrawable`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Clip) only explain how to solve this problem if you set the `Drawable` in XML.

Comment: Can't you just modify the `width` and `height` arguments of `setBounds`? I'm not an android dev, but seeing how you pass it into the `ClipDrawable`, which has a `setBounds` method, I would assume so. After reading your post for a second time, are you having problems displaying an image? If so, you should fit your post to match the problem

Comment: @VinceEmigh Yes, it's not showing up when I call `imageView.setImageDrawable(clipDrawable)`. I'll edit the post. How do you think I should change the arguments of the `setBounds` method?

Comment: check my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30395855/using-clipdrawable-to-hide-a-part-of-and-imageview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's either you need to call `invalidateSelf` on the clipdrawable after you set the level or you should try this:

```
imageView.setBackground(clipDrawable);
imageView.setImageResource(android.R.color.transparent);
```

Courtesy of: [Using ClipDrawable to hide a part of and ImageView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30395855/using-clipdrawable-to-hide-a-part-of-and-imageview)